# Как можно передать документ на печать с сервера?

Tags: python, веб-программирование

Каким образом можно реализовать систему передачи документа в печать напрямую в принтер как в этом видео? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3JmJWDMmcI&feature=youtu.be
Что это за приставка? Роутер? Как это можно сделать на Python, с помощью каких библиотек и протоколов?

Comment: Вроде это плоттер.

Comment: 1) Сделать бота / сервер 2) На компе где запущен бот/сервер вызывать метод печати (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22550163/5909792) 3) отправить сгенерированный или заранее подготовленный файл на печать

Comment: но по этой ссылке используется модуль os, проблема в том, что нужно отправить его на печать с сервера на удаленный принтер

Comment: @АликсПлисов, пишите `@gil9red`, чтобы уведомление о комментарии получил пользователь (я сюда зашел только потому, что увидел другой ваш вопрос и стало интересно, что ответили в предыдущем). Ссылка на один из ответов по вопросу, выше был ответ (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12725233/5909792), а в нем ссылка на этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464974/5909792, где приводится пример использования `win32api.ShellExecute` с `gsprint`. Тема не такая простая, как кажется, особенно если требуется указать конкретных принтер в сети, придется гуглить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мелкая белая коробочка - это [**tp-link tl-mr3020**](https://www.tp-link.com/ru/home-networking/3g-4g-router/tl-mr3020/) - роутер, который не умеет печатать сам.

На нем установленна **openwrt** и программа [**p910nd**](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/print_server/p910ndprinterserver) - принт-сервер *jet-direct*.

Проброшен порт jet-direct, этот порт подключается к серверу печати , например, **cups**. Бот может отправить `pdf` файл на cups по протоколу `ipp`( [install the Web Server (IIS) role, the Print Services role, and the Internet Printing role service in the Print Services role.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731368%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_How) - на виндовс сервер можно сделать) или вызовом команды, а купс его переводит на язык принтера и отправляет в принтер.